# How to generate Users list into excel in Hudson?

Tags: hudson

We are migrating our Hudson build tool. So, we need to have list of all users available in the existing Hudson build tool to a Excel sheet with the user name and user id's. Is there any way that I can generate a report in a single shot? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Into Excel? Unless you are going to write a parser yourself, forget about it. But you can still get a list of users on the system in other formats.

To get a list of all users on the system, you first have to know what your authentication realm is.